# Search text into pdf from database

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I'm trying do do a research page that search every pdf from my database that contain the keyword I'm searching.

The problem is I can't have my pdf + the raw text inside my Database (I am extremely short on the space...)

What I am doing right now is when a user search something, On all my pdf, one by one I use a .php I transform the PDF into raw text then search for the keywords... But this is really long before having a result. and I fear when they'll be many user my server won't like it. (I just assume that I've never used server before and I don't really know what is good or bad)

Would it be worth it for me to add space on my server to put all the raw text from my pdf into the database aswell so I can search with Mysql query ? or is there a smarter way to do it i didn't think of ?

(I don't have the PDF inside the database, just the path, so i can't get space on that)

Comment: Interesting topic - that is a very big deal to a lot of enterprises around the world (upvote!). One solution: on a page where a user is uploading a pdf (or any other type) of file, there is/are fields for metadata. Obviously takes user intervention (have to sell the concept of time/cost savings). Those keywords would then be saved in the MySQL db and searched. And +1 on not storing the pdf in the db; just the link.

Comment: I might use keyword aswell, seems like a good idea, but the search wont be as precise.